# Ruby on rails Socksify issue

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, tor

Im using a `rake task` to perform massive update, but i need to change my ip address constantly and im using Tor for that.
Now, Tor doesn't flows all my ruby command prompt traffic so im using  [Ruby Socksify](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/) but im getting this:

```
    cannot load such file -socksify
```

Here is my code:

```
    require 'socksify'
    TCPSocket::socks_server = "127.0.0.1"
    TCPSocket::socks_port = 9050
```

already did `gem install socksify`

Any advice?
Also, is there any other way to perform this? Already used advance tor but it fails at connecting to remote mysql database i get `Reading authorization packet` error :(

Comment: Which version of ruby are you working with? Are you using `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage versions?

Comment: In this case im using windows and rubyinstaller. Ruby 1.9.3-p125. Tried on my alt machine with rvm and i have the same issue.

Comment: `cannot load such file` error message usually means the gem is not accessible. Run `gem list` command from that folder and verify that `socksify` does show up in the list. Also, I would recommend using a project specific rvm gemset to easily manage dependencies of the project. See https://rvm.io/workflow/projects/ for more info.